# Debezium connector error for source cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, debezium, connector, cdc

I installed debezium 2.4, cassandra 3.11.9 and kafka latest with dockerize.
My cassandra table:

```
cqlsh> desc test.foo;

CREATE TABLE test.foo (
     a int PRIMARY KEY,
     b text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
     AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
     AND cdc = true
```

I entered my debezium container with bash.

```
=>> docker exec -it source-debezium-1 /bin/bash
```

I created the "debezium-connector-cassandra" file in the /kafka/connect directory and created the "debezium-cassandra-connector.properties" file inside.
my debezium-cassandra-connector.properties:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrBqF.png)

Then I ran the following command.

```
  java -jar /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-cassandra/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.1.1.Final-jar-with-dependencies.jar /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-cassandra/debezium-cassandra-connector. properties > debezium.stdout.log 2> debezium.stderr.log
```

and I get the following error:

```
  [kafka@57ccaff8016f ~]$ cat debezium.stderr.log
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate file:////var/lib/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml. If this is a local file, please confirm you've provided file:/// as a URI prefix.
at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:268)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:186)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:157)
at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorContext.loadDdlFromDisk(CassandraConnectorContext.java:64)
at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorContext.<init>(CassandraConnectorContext.java:36)
at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorTask.run(CassandraConnectorTask.java:72)
at io.debezium.connector.cassandra.CassandraConnectorTask.main(CassandraConnectorTask.java:61)
```

can you support me?

I checked my cassandra container. cassandra.yaml location is correct. I made the necessary configurations, but my connector is not working.